# Cannot resolve specific DNS

Tags: networking, router, dns

For two days now I've been unable to access [slack.com](https://slack.com), which is a website I used frequently on this computer before. I also cannot access the website on my phone, but *only* if I use my router's Wi-Fi. It resolves fine if I go over LTE.

When I use the `ping` command it also immediately fails:

```
C:\> ping slack.com
Ping request could not find host slack.com. Please check the name and try again.
```

`nslookup` gives me this:

```
C:\> nslookup slack.com
Server:  Speedport.ip
Address:  fe80::1
```

A weird result in my eyes, but Google does the same, so I don't know what's going on:

```
C:\> nslookup google.com
Server:  Speedport.ip
Address:  fe80::1
```

Next thing I tried was going to [this website](http://ping.eu/nslookup/) and resolving the address from there. It gave me IP `52.85.241.83` as result, but when I try to directly enter that in my browser I get this error:

```
ERROR
The request could not be satisfied.
Bad request.

Generated by cloudfront (CloudFront)
Request ID: hidfYeGpc4tg8uQbRQ9TUWBizCxLgBeAvoC_il_V0kRI4T46j_YnHw==
```

The truly curious part, however, is that it works fine if I use a VPN over my university's private VPN network.

I'm not terribly experienced with routing stuff, so I don't know what to do here. This happened from one moment to another, but I can't recall exactly what I did.

My router is a Speedport W 724V.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the actual problem is the DNS in your internal network. Often times, internal network devices are connected to the one and only one DNS server (i.e., your router). If your router doesn't resolve the DNS request of slack.com then it wouldn't be able to tell your computer where it should go.

However, as you have mentioned that you are able to access the site via a VPN network, that suggests that the DNS configuration at the remote site is configured properly to map the address of slack.com and that's why you can access slack.com from the VPN network.

One of the solutions to this problem is to set the DNS Server addresses manually. Without having to query the server's IP address with your router, it can be set to querying Google's DNS Server.

In a nutshell, if you wish to have access to slack.com for all your devices connecting to your Wi-Fi network, you should then change the DNS Server addresses in the WAN Configuration to the following:

```
Primary DNS Address: 8.8.8.8
Secondary DNS Address: 8.8.4.4
```

However, if you are unfamiliar with changing the WAN settings in your router, then you could do so by changing the IPv4 Configuration in your Network Adapter. See more in Google's [Get Started – Configure your network settings to use Google Public DNS](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/using) document.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to tinker with my router settings right now to see if I can reproduce the problem, but I'm guessing that you may have somehow configured your router to use IPv6 exclusively.  I'd look at the router management page (can you get there?) and see if you can turn IPv4 back on (if it is indeed turned off).

Although I'm not sure how the university private VPN works... unless it's IPv6 or a local address that doesn't require routing.